# What is the PHP error log remote location?

Tags: php, logging, error-handling, error-log

In PHP, I am using this code to define where to log errors:

```
ini_set('error_log', dirname(__FILE__) . '/err_logs/error_log.txt');
```

On a normal server it works great, but I am using [Heroku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroku) and apparently when the virtual machine is terminated and then restarted, I lose the error log text file!

Can I store the error log text file onto a remote location?

Comment: Of course, email it, ftp it, http post it, cron script to move it, dropbox it.  How would you like to do it?

Comment: Check out this answer I wrote a few days ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13563078/how-do-i-set-up-php-logging-to-go-to-a-remote-server/13564632#13564632

Comment: Michel: thanks for the input but then I would need a server always listening.. a ftp transfer would be enough for me!

Comment: shapeshifter: how about this: if the log exist then copy it to ftp.. ps: how would I prevent overwriting? copying to a folder with a different timestamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) job that emails you the log every day. Or, you can move it using SSH, FTP, or a web service.

Comment: I created a cron that emails the logfile every 30 minutes and then deletes the file. FTP_PUT command is not available in heroku due to the dyno isolation... so had to find another solution! Thanks