# Newlines get stripped in syslog-ng

Tags: php, logging, syslog, syslog-ng

We have implemented centralised logging using syslog-ng on our load balanced servers. The history of that setup can be seen here: [How do I set up PHP Logging to go to a remote server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13563078/how-do-i-set-up-php-logging-to-go-to-a-remote-server) .
It's working fine but the newlines are getting stripped at the destination. Is there any way to keep the newlines intact? Here's our config:

*Source*

```
destination php { tcp("server.com" port(xxxx)); };  
log { source(s_all); filter(f_php); destination(php); };  
filter f_php { facility(user); };
```

*Destination*

```
destination d_php { file("$PROGRAM" owner(www-data) group(www-data) perm(0644)); };  
filter f_php { program("^\/var\/log\/"); };  
log { source(s_all); filter(f_php); destination(d_php); flags(final); };
```

Comment: There's another issue that we just discovered. Log messages are getting truncated at 500 characters. This looks like a hard limit in the syslog protocol which might require recompiling from source. We're hoping not to go down that path. Has anyone encountered this before?

Comment: Just an update for the previous comment. Logs were not getting truncated, rather they were being split every 500 characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the syslog template format for the destination and manually add the newline at the end. For example, here's a template I use for one of my customized syslog-ng streams. I change the date format (to be more easily parsed by a script). Notice the "\n" at the end.

```
file("$PROGRAM"
        template("$R_ISODATE $HOST_FROM $MSGHDR$MSG\n")
        template_escape(no)
);
```

See the [syslog-ng docs](http://www.balabit.com/sites/default/files/documents/syslog-ng-v3.0-guide-admin-en.html/index.html-single.html) for information on the various `$VARS` you can use.